# Autosign off-chain signatures in 1/n Gnosis Safe

Tags: gnosis-safe, signature, walletconnect, off-chain, eip-1271

I'm playing around with the WalletConnect off-chain signature repo: https://github.com/5afe/eip-1271-dapp/tree/main and I'm trying to find a way to create off-chain signed proposals without having to pair the browser and Gnosis Custom App and keep the browser tab open and switch to it to sign emitted messages from the Custom App.

I want to simplify and integrate the flow for UIs and create V4 Typed Data signatures that are saved in the Gnosis Off-chain API.

Does anyone know if I can achieve the same outcome for a (1/n) Gnosis Safe threshold that just needs your own vote to create and store an off-chain proposal?

EDIT: added the entire flow from top to bottom with how it's working right now by pairing the Custom App with Gnosis Page open in another tab where the signing happens.

Thank you very much in advance!

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm unsure if I understand the goal entirely, so I'll leave a comment instead of an answer. Signing messages automatically sounds like a bad idea from a security perspective, as you could sign a malicious message without even checking it. But if you want it, you could use your owner's private key to sign the messages. The implementation depends on many variables which are unclear from the question.

Comment: Thank you @mikheevm, I have 3 gnosis safes. The first one, let's call it OPERATOR requires  2/3 votes and if we add a new one we go to 3/4. The second layer COMPANIES (1/n) and a third gnosis for COMPANIES EMPLOYEES. I want to catch and store signed proposal intentions.

Comment: Phone died  and can't edit my comment but to add more context. We want the third gnosis which are the employs to sign an off-chain typed data with an (NFT ID, URL, receiverAddress) and then the second gnosis will curate the proposal in their UI Dashboard and actually propose to the 1st gnosis to mint the NFT proposed by the offchain signed message from the 3rd gnosis.